# Prevent Mysql from overwriting data

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, web

I am trying to add more data (join) to my existing string in column `purchased`

I use this PHP code:

```
 $id=$_GET["id"];    
 $username=$_SESSION['username'];
 $sql="UPDATE `users` SET `purchased` = `purchased`.' $id' WHERE `username`='$username'";
 mysql_query($sql);
```

If current user's `purchased` column contains value `0` then after this query (id=1) it should become

`0 1` but its overwriting existing data and becoming `1`  how can i join this `(space)1` to existing `0` in my Mysql column without overwriting anything , by just joining to existing string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved By getting existing value and joining strings in PHP

```
$id = $_GET["id"];    
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$sql = "SELECT `purchased` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";
$data = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($data)) {
    $ep = $row[0];
}
$newData = ''.$ep.' '.$id.'';
$sql="UPDATE `users` SET `purchased` = '$newData' WHERE `username`='$username'";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Please always use [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php) coding standards in Core PHP programming.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer :

```
$id = $_GET["id"];    
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDatabase', $username, $password);
    $sth = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE `users` SET `purchased` = CONCAT(`purchased`,?) WHERE `username`=?');
    $sth->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->bindParam(2, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->execute();
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Please always use [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php) coding standards in Core PHP programming.